# Updating apex trigger. Task/Account/Owner relationship

Tags: apex

We have a trigger that updates a field on the account object. I am trying to update it so that it uses the task assigned to user, rather than CreatedBy.
I tried updating CreatedBy.Department OwnerId.Department and it's throwing me the error:

> Didn't understand relationship 'OwnerId' in field path. If you are
> attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r'
> after the custom relationship name.

```
List<Account> listAccountsWithTask = [select Id, Account_Activity_Date__c, (select LastModifiedDate, CreatedBy.CompanyName from Tasks where Status = 'Completed' and CreatedBy.Department = 'Customer Success' order by LastModifiedDate desc limit 1) from Account where id in :setAccountId];
```

What the correct syntax to use OwnerId?

Answer (score 0):

Standard relationship field names take the form `<name>Id`.

OpportunityId, AccountId, OwnerId, ParentId, CreatedById, etc...

When you start traversing up the relationship, you use the field name without the "Id" at the end.

So when you want to access `Department` on the user specified by `CreatedById`, you drop the "Id" and use dot-notation.
`CreatedBy.Department`

Same thing applies with `OwnerId`. You want to use
`Owner.Department`.

The analog for custom relationship fields is to replace `__c` with `__r`.
`My_Account_Lookup__c` => `My_Account_Lookup__r.Name`

Comment: When I tried that, I was getting a similar error: No such column 'Department' on entity 'Name'

Comment: @MattC You should edit your question to include that attempt, as well as the _exact_ error message that you're getting. Not including details like this makes answering a question a guessing game, and knowledgeable people are going to get tired of that really quickly.

Comment: @MattC - If the Task is owned by a Queue, there is no `Owner.Department` - you need to do polymorphic querying

Comment: @cropredy it is not owned by a queue.